# How can I get terminal output in python?

Tags: python, terminal

I can execute a terminal command using `os.system()` but I want to capture the output of this command. How can I do this?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> cmd = [ 'echo', 'arg1', 'arg2' ]
>>> output = subprocess.Popen( cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE ).communicate()[0]
>>> print(output)
arg1 arg2
```

There is a bug in using of the subprocess.PIPE. For the huge output use this:

```
import subprocess
import tempfile

with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as tempf:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['echo', 'a', 'b'], stdout=tempf)
    proc.wait()
    tempf.seek(0)
    print(tempf.read())
```

Comment: you are my savior!!! i have been looking for something like this for days!!! thank you!

Answer (score 33):

The recommended way in Python 3.5 and above is to use [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run):

```
from subprocess import run
output = run("pwd", capture_output=True).stdout
```

Comment: PIPE is not defined

Comment: @Cherona It's deifned in the `subprocess` module, so you need to import it.

Comment: I also updated the answer with the most recent API to do this.

Comment: How can I explicitly open read from a terminal? (If stdin has already been redirected to reading from a shell pipe?)

Comment: @HelenCraigman I don't think that's possible. If stdin is not connected to a terminal, what terminal would you like to read from?

Comment: @sven When I pipe to a python program (for example, in ubuntu:


`cat file.txt | python3 program.py`,


I would like to have the python program read lines from "file.txt", and interact with the user at the terminal

Comment: @sven (Or, actually in my case: `script.sh | python3 program.py`). stdin reads lines from the pipe, and I need the user to interact with the Python program.

Comment: @HelenCraigman I see. On Unix, you can still read from the "controlling terminal" by opening `/dev/tty` for reading and writing. I'm not sure that pattern is a good idea, though.

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: On Win10 and Python 3.7.9. this now results in the line `output = run("pwd", capture_output=True).stdout` failing with error: `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`.

Comment: @lazarea On Windows, there is no `pwd` executable. The name of the executable is just an example.

Answer (score 15):

You can use [Popen](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) in `subprocess` as they suggest.

with `os`, which is not recomment, it's like below:

```
import os
a  = os.popen('pwd').readlines()
```

Comment: This does not work.  `Popen` objects have no `readlines()` method.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, it only works for os.popen

Comment: `os.popen` is deprecated in favour of `subprocess.Popen`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the library commands

```
import commands
print commands.getstatusoutput('echo "test" | wc')
```

Comment: Where do you get the commands module? It doesn't appear to be on pip for Python3.

Comment: @Shule commands is an older module. It is replaced by the subprocess module. https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output