# How to get terminal output?

Tags: python, subprocess, raspberry-pi

**Background**

As a fun project, I have decided to create a remote control application for my new Raspberry Pi. I know how to use SSH, but I wanted to implement somthing similar in Python. How can I get the text that is printed out onto the terminal to display in my Python shell?

I checked out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4408377/1993598), but it did not work. By did not work, I mean that I am not able to see the output text. If I enter `passwd`, it gives me only

```
Changing password for User.
```

But it does not give me the interactive session. *THAT* is what I am trying to figure out.

**NOTE:** my Raspberry Pi is running on “Wheezy.” Also, it would be great if this program could work with other operating systems (such as Windows 7, Mac OS X).

**Code**

```
import subprocess
import socket
import sys
import platform
import os

print "WELCOME TO xTROL. \n"

pyVER = sys.version
OS = platform.system()

print pyVER, "\n"
print "Running on %s" % (OS)
while True:
    INPUT = raw_input(">>>")
    cmd_FORMAT = INPUT.split()

    try:
        output = subprocess.Popen(cmd_FORMAT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
        print output
    except Exception:
        print "Something went wrong."
```

Comment: What do you mean by "but it did not work."?

Comment: @MostafaR The output did not show.

Comment: Can you show us exactly what you're doing so we can help diagnose?

Comment: @xxmbabanexx Maybe you're doing something wrong, As Kyle said it's better to show what you're doing exactly.

Comment: @MostafaR Ok, this is *exactly* what I did. I used the `Popen` subprocess command, and did the code as above. When I execute a terminal command, *nothing* happens.

Comment: @KyleMaxwell I have shown you *exactly* what I have done. If you need extra information, please tell me what it is.

Comment: `cmd` is not defined in this code. Otherwise, it should work unless your commands do not output anything in stdout.

Comment: For me it works for simple commands (Of course by changing cmd_FORMAT to cmd), But i think it have bugs with complex command lines. You can show us what is the command that you're trying to run.

Comment: @MostafaR I tried to run Python from the Terminal (Just put "Python" into the code). When I do this, it only returns a blank line.

Comment: Yes, that's expected. Interactive programs do not work this way.

Comment: This is interesting. I ran the file thru ssh, and it works perfectly. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write something like SSH, you'll have to make a pseudo-terminal. Look at [the `pty` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pty.html).