# read real-time data from terminal via python

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, subprocess, real-time

I have a Sensor that is connected to my ubuntu laptop. There is a small programm that plots the sensor values in a terminal in real-time.

I wanna read out these values and plot them in a smooth graph with python.
Is this possible? Even with python3?

I tried the subprocess command like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408377/how-can-i-get-terminal-output-in-python). But it does not work.

Comment: `for line in proc.stdout:print(line)`

Comment: *" it does not work."* is not very informative. Start with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17698359/4279) and [provide a minimal but complete code example that shows the error](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).