# Capturing output from Popen

Tags: python, stdout

Maybe what I need is a general explanation of what `STDOUT` is, but here's my problem. I need to run a shell script within python on a bunch of pairs of files, and parse the output. If I run:

```
from itertools import combinations
from subprocess import Popen

for pair in combinations(all_ssu, 2):
    Popen(
        ['blastn',
        '-query', 'tmp/{0}.fna'.format(pair[0]),
        '-subject', 'tmp/{0}.fna'.format(pair[1]),
        '-outfmt', '6 qseqid sseqid pident'
        ],
    )
```

... it seems to work great (note: `all_ssu` is a list of file names essentially). The shell prints a bunch of lines of data that I'd like to compare. So how do I get that printed data into a list or a dataframe or something so that I can use it?

After looking around the docs and some other questions here, it looks like the `stdout` flag is looking for a file object, so I tried:

```
from itertools import combinations
from subprocess import Popen
for pair in combinations(all_ssu, 2):
    out_file = open('tmp.txt', 'rw')
    Popen(
        ['blastn',
        '-query', 'tmp/{0}.fna'.format(pair[0]),
        '-subject', 'tmp/{0}.fna'.format(pair[1]),
        '-outfmt', '6 qseqid sseqid pident'
        ],
        stdout=out_file
    )
    for line in out_file.readlines():
        print line
    out_file.close()
```

And this also seems to work, except that I create that temporary file that I don't need. I tried just setting a variable `captured` to `None` and then putting `stdout=captured`, but in this case it's just setting `captured` to 0. I also tried `out = Popen(...)` without the `stdout` flag, but again, `out` is just `int(0)`. I also tried playing around with `PIPE`, but couldn't make heads or tails of it.

So the question is: how do I just capture the output from `Popen` directly?

Comment: When you use `PIPE`, you read from the pipe using `Popen.communicate`. The Python online docs do have good examples of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
from itertools import combinations
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
for pair in combinations(all_ssu, 2):
    out = Popen(
        ['blastn',
        '-query', 'tmp/{0}.fna'.format(pair[0]),
        '-subject', 'tmp/{0}.fna'.format(pair[1]),
        '-outfmt', '6 qseqid sseqid pident'
        ],
        stdout=PIPE
    ).communicate[0]
    print(out)
```

from [How can I get terminal output in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408377/how-can-i-get-terminal-output-in-python)

STDOUT is just the standard output for the program, which is the file where anything that the program prints will be written to.

If you want the outputs as a list then you can just create an empty list (`l = []` or something) before the loop and do `l.append(out)` at the end of each iteration of the loop

Answer (score 3):

From Python 2.7 onwards , you can use - [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)

It returns the output of the executed command back as a byte string.

Example -

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> s = subprocess.check_output(["echo","Hello World!"], shell=True)
>>> s
b'"Hello World!"\r\n'
```

I had to use `shell=True` on my windows for this to work, but on linux this may not be needed.

Comment: Note that `subprocess.check_output` is new in Python 2.7. Usually that's not a problem, but it's good to keep in mind.

Comment: Thanks, added that to the answer.