# How can i retrieve the output shown on my command line using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, subprocess

Using ubuntu 16.04 what i want is to retrieve the output on terminal using python, i did refer to these 2 links :
[How can I get terminal output in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408377/how-can-i-get-terminal-output-in-python)

[Running shell command from Python and capturing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-from-python-and-capturing-the-output)

but being a starter in python i couldn't make it work, my original code which output i want:

```
for element in my_images:
    os.system('you-get -o videos ' + element)
```

how my code became :

```
for element in my_images:
    # value = os.system('you-get -o videos ' + element)
    output = subprocess.Popen(os.system('you-get -o videos ' + element), stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
    print(output)
```

but it didn't work i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_twitter.py", line 29, in <module>
    output = subprocess.Popen(os.system('you-get -o videos ' + element), stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1220, in _execute_child
    args = list(args)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: When you use a `subprocess` you shouldn't use the `os.system` command, which returns an integer. You should just run the command as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the constructor of `Popen` with the command and arguments directly. Calling `os.system` would execute the command and return the exit code, which is not what you want to pass to `Popen`:

```
output = subprocess.Popen('you-get -o videos ' + element, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

Comment: when i print the output i just get b' ' there is nothing even inside the quotes.

Comment: There may have been an error from your `you-get` command. You should check what the error message says in the second item of the tuple returned by the `communicate` method (change `[0]` to `[1]`).

Comment: That is correct some crashed other worked but i get None for both that worked and crashed now.

Comment: And for the one that work i did get not understandable output, i tried to decode using  print(output).decode('utf-8') but it didn't work.