# How to print to terminal window from subprocessed python script

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I create a subprocess running a python script like this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['nohup', 'python', 'listen.py'],
                     cwd="/execute",
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

I then let the spawning thread terminate; and the spawned subprocess remains running. The user (me) is back at the bash terminal.

I wish to print to this terminal from within the subprocess (from listen.py) - how can I achieve this?

Comment: [I think you will be able to find your solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408377/how-can-i-get-terminal-output-in-python)

Comment: Those are all for how to print from the spawning script - I'd like to know if it's possible to do it from the *spawned* script.

Answer (score 4):

With `nohup`, you simply can't. One of the features of `nohup` is that it detaches the started process from any terminal.

Without `nohup`, in the trivial case, simply don't use the `stdin`, `stdout`, or `stderr` keyword arguments to `Popen()` at all; the subprocess will inherit copies of these file descriptors from the calling process.

Having a background process write to your terminal while you are using it can be extremely disruptive, though; a better solution is usually to have the process write to a log file, which you can `tail -f` if you want to, in a different terminal or another program if you like.

Comment: Is it possible to have the proceed continue once the spawning process has terminated without nohup?

Comment: Huh? With `Popen` the parent and child run in parallel.

Comment: Or do you mean does the subprocess continue to run after the parent exits? Yes, it does (as you can easily verify yourself).

Answer (score 1):

So script A spawns script B and terminates, and then you want to access the stdout of script B?

The first thing is that you probably don't want to capture the stdout from script B in A. But the stdout has to go somewhere, such as to a file (solution 2) or it can just be inherited stdout from the parent process (solution 1).

### Solution 1

The following will exit to the shell immediately then write "123" to the same terminal 3 seconds later. If you pipe script A to a file then the outputs of script B will go there too.

```sh
python -c "import subprocess; subprocess.Popen(['python', '-c', 'import time; time.sleep(3); print(123)'])"
```

### Solution 2

If you want script A to output to the terminal, but for script B's output to be stored somewhere else then you can write it to a file directly, such as by providing the file as the stdout kwarg to Popen like so:

```py
p = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'listen.py'],
                     cwd="/execute",
                     stdout=open('/execute/results.txt', 'w'),
                     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

### Solution 3

Or if you specifically want to use nohup then the following will by usually default write the output from the subprocess to nohup.txt

```py
p = subprocess.Popen(['nohup', 'python', 'listen.py'],
                     cwd="/execute",
                     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Comment: **Solution 2** looks promising.